# How to retrieve the value of ng-input in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, ngx-chips

I'm using `Angular 6` and the module `ngx-chips` to use `ng-input` field, so this is the HTML template:

```
      <div class="form-group container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class=" col-sm-12">
            <label for="FormControlAlias"
              class="col-sm-2 col-form-label float-left">Alias</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 float-left" >
              <tag-input #alias [(ngModel)]="aliasList"
                [secondaryPlaceholder]="'Enter the project aliases'"
                [placeholder]="'Enter an alias'"
                [modelAsStrings]="true"
                name="alias" [separatorKeyCodes]="[188]" > </tag-input>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="addAlias(alias.value);>Add</button>
```

Here is the function I call by clicking the button:

```
addAlias( alias: Array<string>): void {

    console.log(alias.value);

}
```

in the console I get this error :

```
ERROR TypeError: "alias is undefined"
```

I want to get the value of #alias and make a post request into the database, but I can't retrieve the value.

Comment: What is meaning of alias.value in (click)?

Comment: the content of the ng-input. The user inserts some values into the ng-input field and they are passed to the function addAlias()

Comment: You already have those values in `aliasList`. Just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define aliasList as a variable in your class.

After you can retreive the value with :

```
addAlias(): void{
    console.log(this.aliasList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not send `alias` value from template. You already have those values in `aliasList` set via `ngModel`. Just use that.

```
addAlias() {
    console.log(this.aliasList);
}
```

template

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="addAlias()">Add</button>
```